# OSGI cache directory

Tags: java, osgi

I have a Java OSGI application, and it seems that the OSGI cache directory being created on every run and contains 300M (mostly JARs), and being cleaned when the application being closed.
It causes us performance issues (redundant IO operations).

Is there a way to use the same directory on multiple runs?
Can we run without creating this directory?

Thanks

Comment: Which OSGi container are you using?

Comment: @Progman Apache Felix

Answer (score 1):

First, this is an issue for the *management agent* you are using. A management agent is responsible for installing, updating, and uninstalling a bundles. For example, Karaf has a management agent that is based on maven, bnd has its own launcher that has an *executable jar* approach as management agent. So you need to first understand how your management agent works.

That set, OSGi does provide a mechanisms that management agents can leverage.

- **by reference** – In general a bundle is installed by providing a URL to the OSGi framework. If this URL is a `file:` url and prefixed with `reference:` then the framework will install the bundle *by reference*. By default, the framework copies the bundle's jar to an inner cache. (Since recently bnd's launcher can create executable JARs that install by reference.)
- `org.osgi.framework.storage.clean` – This system property controls if the cache area is cleaned or not If you set it to `none` then nothing is flashed. If set to `onFirstInit` it will clear every time you start the framework.

As said, you need to know the details of who is your management agent to properly optimize this.